# WPF binding to element that is binded

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a enum in view model and a combobox in xaml

```
<TextBlock>Profession</TextBlock>                     
<TextBox Name="txtSpec" Text="{Binding Speciality}" />
<ComboBox Name="cmbSpec" SelectedIndex="{Binding ElementName=txtSpec, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource EnumConverter}, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}">
    <ComboBoxItem>Software engineer</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Mechanic</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

txtSpec binded Speciality. When combobox selection changed, txtSpec's text changes but it does not notify that property have changed. And i can't determine that object is dirty or not.
What is wrong in my code? Thanks.

I solved this problem by

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:Converter x:Key="EnumConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
...

<ComboBox Name="cmbSpec" SelectedIndex="{Binding Speciality, Converter={StaticResource EnumConverter}}">
    <ComboBoxItem>Software engineer</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Mechanic</ComboBoxItem>

</ComboBox>

...

[ValueConversion(typeof(object), typeof(string))]
public class Converter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (int)((Specialist)value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (Specialist)value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is Speciality a property?

Comment: Yes, Speciality is a property

Comment: You mess around with binding. SelectIndex can alternatively bind to Speciality, effect would be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to bind the `SelectedIndex` simply to `Speciality` too?

```
<TextBlock>Profession</TextBlock>                     
<TextBox Name="txtSpec" Text="{Binding Speciality}" />
<ComboBox Name="cmbSpec" SelectedIndex="{Binding Speciality, Converter={StaticResource EnumConverter}}">
    <ComboBoxItem>Software engineer</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Mechanic</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

It's a more straightforward mode of achieving the same goal in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try a **TwoWay** binding **Mode**?

```
SelectedIndex="{Binding ElementName=txtSpec, Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay"}
```